# Immutability of haskell dequeue

Tags: haskell

I have an application that needs to process some items on a queue.  Sometimes taking off items, sometimes putting on new items.  I am confused about how to achieve this given the immutability of haskell data strucutres.  Here is my experimental code

```
module Main where

import Data.Dequeue as D
import Data.Time
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Monad (forever)


data ScheduledCall = ScheduledCall {
        not_before :: UTCTime
    ,   apiParameters :: String
}

sleep :: Int -> IO ()
sleep n = threadDelay (n * 1000 * 1000)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let workQ :: D.BankersDequeue ScheduledCall
        workQ = D.empty
    now <- getCurrentTime
    forever $ do
        let workQ' = D.pushBack workQ (ScheduledCall now "first")
        -- possibly do something with the items
        let len = length workQ'
        let workQ = workQ'
        putStrLn $ "Length " ++ (show len)
        sleep 5
```

With this code I expect to see the dequeue growing by 1 on each iteration, but it is not.  This implies the structure remains immutable.

How do I use the dequeue through different iterations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use recursion.

```
main = do
   now <- getCurrentTime
   let loop workQ = do
          let workQ' = D.pushBack workQ (ScheduledCall now "first")
          -- possibly do something with the items
          let len = length workQ'
          putStrLn $ "Length " ++ (show len)
          sleep 5
          loop workQ'   -- recurse with the new queue
   loop D.empty  -- start the loop with an initially empty dqueue
```

There are more advanced (and complex) techniques to model mutability, like using `IORef`s, or the `ST`/`State` monads, but for simple cases a basic recursive definition is enough.

---

Note that you can not "reassign" like you tried to do:

```
let workQ = workQ'
putStrLn $ "Length " ++ (show len)
sleep 5
```

This defines a *new* variable `workQ` which is completely unrelated to the other variable with the same name defined above. The scope of the new variable is only the following lines, where it is not used, so it is a useless definition.

You can think of that redefinition like those happening in, say, C++:

```cpp
{
   Dqueue workQ = ... ;
   stuff();
   if (blah) {
      Dqueue workQ = ... ;
      // this does not affect the outer variable
   }
}
```

Defining a variable with the same name as another one defined in an outer scope is called "shadowing". GHC warns about that (if you enable warnings), since it is usually a mistake.

Comment: Does tail recursion mean I don't have to worry about stack overflow here?

Comment: You indeed do not have to worry in this case. Understanding the memory cost of a recursive definition is in general not so obvious, but simple "loops" like the above ones are pretty much standard.

Comment: As a general rule, tail recursion is neither needed nor desirable in most Haskell programs.  In fact, in this specific example, `loop` is not tail recursive, though this fact is obscured by the `do` notation.  Nonetheless, it will never cause a stack overflow.  It's a good idea to try to forget everything you ever learned about recursion in other languages when you're programming Haskell.  Pretend that straightforward, unbounded recursion "just works" until you actually manage to write a program that overflows the stack (or more likely, gobbles gigabytes of memory).